# AssertionError Camel-Test

Tags: java, testing, mocking, apache-camel

I'm new to testing Camel Routes and I have some problem.
I have the following code where I define the route

```
from("jms:preview")
    .to("jms:preview-request")
```

I want to test this route, so I've tried with the following Test code

```
public class RouteTest extends CamelTestSupport  {

    protected RouteBuilder createRoutesBuilder() throws Exception {
        return new MyRouteBuilder();
    }

    @Test
    public void testRoute() throws Exception{
      
        ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("vm://localhost:61616");
        context.addComponent("jms",JmsComponent.jmsComponent(connectionFactory));
        MockEndpoint mock = getMockEndpoint("mock:jms:preview");
        mock.expectedBodiesReceived("request");
        template.sendBodyAndHeader("jms:preview-request,"request","request_type","rss");
        assertMockEndpointsSatisfied();
    }
```

I got the following error
`Received message count. Expected: <1> but was: <0>`.
I have already read other examples but I don't understand where I am wrong.
Can anyone Help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you send it to the wrong endpoint, if you have

```
from("jms:preview")
```

in your route, then you probably should have it like

```
template.sendBodyAndHeader("jms:preview,"request","request_type","rss");
```